# Отправка заданий в Celery внутри Docker-compose

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose, celery

Всем привет. У меня не работает отправка заданий в Celery внутри Docker-compose. Как правильно это делать?

Я использую следующий стек: docker-compose(1.24.0), django(1.11.23),  celery(4.3.0), rabbitmq(3.7.15),  nginx(1.15.12), postgres(9.6), python(3.6).
И периодические задачи через celery-beat работают без проблем. Автообнаружение задач то же работает, т.к. задачи видны на страницы длимитов в flower. 
Но простая задача "печать строки" висит бесконечно долго, если я пробую запустить ее через ipython. Эта же задача добавленная в кастомный метод save модели через какое-то время инициирует ошибку 404 nginx (по таймауту). 
В flower эти задания не попадают.

docker-compose.yml выглядит так:

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./django/webPROJECT:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    links:
      - "django"
    networks:
      - frontend_network


  postgres:
    build: ./postgres/
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      LC_ALL: ru_RU.UTF-8
      POSTGRES_DB: db_django
      ALLOW_IP_RANGE: 0.0.0.0/0
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - backend_network


  django:
    build: ./django/
    container_name: django
    command: bash -c "cd /code/webPROJECT/ && gunicorn FRIGOGLASS.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./django:/code
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - frontend_network
      - backend_network


 celery-worker1:
    build: ./django/
    container_name: celery-worker1
    hostname: worker1
    command: bash -c "cd ./webPROJECT && celery -A FRIGOGLASS worker -l info"
    volumes:
      - ./django:/code
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
    networks:
      - backend_network


  celery-beat:
    build: ./django/
    container_name: celery-beat
    hostname: beat
    command: bash -c "cd ./webPROJECT && celery -A FRIGOGLASS beat -l info"
    volumes:
      - ./django:/code
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
    networks:
      - backend_network


  rabbit:
    container_name: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.15-alpine
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=ххх
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=ххх
    networks:
      - backend_network


  flower:
    container_name: flower
    image: mher/flower
    ports:
      - "8003:8003"
    networks:
      - backend_network


  frontend:      
  build: ./frontend/
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - frontend_network
      - backend_network


networks:
  frontend_network:
    driver: bridge
  backend_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Файл настроек проекта django:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
# Settings Celery
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://ххх:ххх@rabbit:5672'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://ххх:ххх@rabbit:5672'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'hello_cx_oracle_3query': {
        'task': 'APP_main.tasks.hello_cx_oracle_3query',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1')  # execute every minute
    },
}
```

И celery.py в той же директории:

```
import os
from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'FRIGOGLASS.settings')
app = Celery('FRIGOGLASS',
             broker='amqp://ххх:ххх@rabbit:5672',
             backend='rpc://',
             # include=['FRIGOGLASS.tasks'])
             )
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
# # Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(result_expires=3600,)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Само задание в файле tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def test_task():
    """Пример задачи, """
    print('___before test_task___')
    print('___after test_task___')
```

Вызов задания в кастомноми методе save в моделе:

```
from .tasks import test_task
......
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    test_task.delay()
    ......
    super(myModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

В логах контейнера django при сохранении модели:

```
# docker logs django
[2019-08-26 10:26:13 +0300] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.0
[2019-08-26 10:26:13 +0300] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2019-08-26 10:26:13 +0300] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-08-26 10:26:13 +0300] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
Not Found: /favicon.ico
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /favicon.ico
Not Found: /favicon.ico
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /favicon.ico
[2019-08-26 10:27:39 +0300] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:8)
[2019-08-26 10:27:39 +0300] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
[2019-08-26 10:27:39 +0300] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
```

В логах контейнера nginx при сохранении модели:

```
# docker logs nginx
......
192.168.61.82 - - [26/Aug/2019:10:27:04 +0300] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14875 "http://192.168.60.203/admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-"
2019/08/26 10:27:39 [error] 6#6: *5 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.61.82, server: localhost, request: "POST /admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.4:8000/admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/", host: "192.168.60.203", referrer: "http://192.168.60.203/admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/"
2019/08/26 10:27:39 [error] 6#6: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.61.82, server: localhost, request: "POST /admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.4:8000/admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/", host: "192.168.60.203", referrer: "http://192.168.60.203/admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/"
192.168.61.82 - - [26/Aug/2019:10:27:39 +0300] "POST /admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 154 "http://192.168.60.203/admin/APP_watch_file/task/4/change/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-"
```

В логах контейнеров celery есть только упоминания об обнаруженых задачах. Задача test_task там отсутствует.

При попытке запустить эту задачу через ipython она может висеть бесконечно долго, пока я ее не прерву по Ctrl+C.

```
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
from APP_watch_file.tasks import test_task
test_task.delay()
^C
```

Comment: Конфигурационный файл nginx для контейнера:
      upstream backend {
        server django:8000;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        charset utf-8;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решилась внимательным повторением примера из [документации](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

А имменно - созданием файла **init**.py в директории настроек проекта с содержимым:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals    
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Comment: Потратил целый день на решение проблемы самостоятельно, перед тем как задать вопрос. Задал вопрос - и нашел орешение через 10 минут ))